# How can I change the autonumbering criterion?

Tags: formatting

In a notebook I have three cells whose format is DisplayFormulaNumbered:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

and in a text cell I refer to them respectively as (1) (2) (3), where (1) (2) and (3) have been automatically assigned by Mathematica.

Now, when I add a fourth cell, between the first and second

```
a=1
d=4
b=2
c=3
```

the number 2 is assigned to the cell containing d=4 and other numbers are shifted according that. Therefore the corrispondence in my text is destroyed.

How can I fix this problem ? Two hypotheses:

(a) changing the autunumbering criterion from positional to chronological
(b) automating cross referencing within the notebook

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should tag your cell and use the automatic numbering so that it always links back to a specific cell and its counter. There should be examples on here how to do that. If not I'll post something tomorrow if no one else has.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !! I will keep constantly a watchful eye on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method that seems to work for me, which I think is along the lines of what Mike Honeychurch was referring to in his comment:

1. **Tag the cells**: Select each formatted cell that contain an equation and add a unique tag to each using Cell -> Cell Tags -> Add/Remove cell tags (or CTRL+J).
2. **Add the links**: In the appropriate position within your text cell, insert and automatic numbering link. Navigate to Insert -> Automatic Numbering; select the appropriate counter category from the drop-down menu (e.g. `DisplayFormulaNumbered` in your case), then select the tag you want to refer back to in the list provided.

You should now have a reference in your text cell that will update to reflect the number assigned to the corresponding formula / equation.

Comment: Thanks! It works just as expected. A more little doubt: sometime the counter start from 0, instead from 1; what is this produced by ? Up to now, I haven't been capable to replicate this behavior: it seems happen randomly, but surely it's my fault.

Comment: @mitochondrial I suspect it may happen when you select a category that does not contain any items by mistake; then the count will reflect that there are zero objects of that kind in the notebook.